# Is it possible to Grant Roles to Users in a Stored Procedure?

Tags: db2, data-warehouse

I am working on DB2 Data Warehouse. I am trying to write a stored procedure that involves Granting a input user a role.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE MYSCHEMA.PROCEDURE SP_CHECKIN_USER (
IN userid varchar(9),
IN groupid varchar(10)
) LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN

-- do some work here
GRANT ROLE groupid TO USER userid;

END
```

When I try to run this I get the error:

```
"GROUPID" is undefined name .. SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, DRIVER=...
Run of routine failed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible if you use dynamic SQL for the `grant role` inside the strored procedure.

For example:

```
   declare v_sql varchar(1024);
   set v_sql = 'grant role '||trim(p_groupid)||' to user '||trim(p_userid)||' ';
   execute immediate v_sql;
```

Remember that all other rules still apply, the role must pre-exist, the user must pre-exist, the authid must have all relevant permissions etc.